# Xamarin Player startup error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Tried to deploy my 'hello world' (xamarin.forms) to Xamarin Android Player.

The error message:
"Failed to initialize device Nexus 5 (kitKat)"

Can't Determine if device is valid - disk with UUID {Guid} has no parent.

I tried to manually start the VM from VirtualBox and it work but i cant deploy my code from vs.net. It will shutdown my virtualbox vm and tried to launch Xamarin Android Player vm but with the above error message.

Please advise.[image]

Comment: As a workaround you may be able to use adb connect to make VS aware of your VirtualBox android instance.

Comment: Can you justify how i can use db connect to make VS aware of mine VirtualBox android instance

Comment: VirtualBox assigns an ip to each vritual device instance, you can use adb connect x.x.x.x to let the android debugging system know about this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before installing Xamarin player i have install the gen emotion so that oracle virtual box version is not match with the Xamarin player. So once uninstall the oracle virtual box and re-install Xamarin player it working ok with me

Comment: Vote up to answer :) @KishorBikramOli